# Percentage height inside a viewport unit div won't work in Safari

Tags: css, height, viewport-units, safari7

I have a 100% tall div based on the viewport using the vh unit:

```
div {
    height:100vh;
    background:red;
}
```

Inside this 100% tall div, i need a 50% tall div:

```
span {
    display:block;
    height:50%;
    background:blue;
}
```

Works fine in Chrome, not so good in Safari. Thought its should work, but only works when i'm using a fixed value for the parent div height. Its not working in mobile safari too with latest iOS 7.1

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/qQ8dm/

Works with fixed height: http://jsfiddle.net/xbBcy/ & http://jsfiddle.net/xbBcy/1/

I know, i could use 50vh for the parent div, but a simply percentage height might be better for cross browser compatibility, easier to create a fallback, if i only use vh unit once.

Comment: That works perfectly for me on Chrome 33 on OSX...

Comment: Works for me - Chrome 33/IE 10 on Windows 7/8.1

Comment: And on Chrome 33 on Windows 8.1

Comment: What browser are you using? http://caniuse.com/viewport-units

Comment: Safari 7.0.1, so looks like its a browser bug, i'll updated the question...

Comment: having the same problem. is there any workaround in pure css? if not, javascript is to be used.

Comment: This bug was fixed in Safari 8

Comment: @StephanMuller, I have safary version 9.1.2 - and the bug is exist...

Comment: seeing this issue also in Safari 10.

Comment: to be more specific: I'm seeing this behavior when a parent container is using `min-height: 50vh` and the child is using `height: 100%`.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this to your stylesheet:

```
html, body{
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
```